# Mongodb dynamic like operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In mongodb the equivalent to sql "like" operator is

```
db.users.find({"shows": /m/})
```

Using nodejs/javascript I want to dynamically change letter, based on url paramater.

I have tried

```
letter = req.params.letter;

db.users.find({"shows": '/' + letter + '/'})
```

This doesn't work, I guess because the slashes are now strings are interpreted differently.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to do it, according to the [documentation page:](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

```
db.users.find( { shows : { $regex : letter } } );
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex

Comment: This is working fine but i want to search from multiple fields see below my code

Comment: var searchVar = req.body.search;
Product.find({name : { $regex : searchVar },sku : { $regex : searchVar }},function(error,fetchSearchProduct){});

I need get same result with both cases "test" and "Test" . now its working for "Test" not for "test"

Answer (score 2):

+1 for mindandmedia on the syntax.  However, please remember, that if you want the query to use an index **efficiently**, you have to use prefix queries (also called rooted regexps) like /^prefix/

Your query is likely to be horribly slow otherwise - see the note in the docs here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let filter = "Dynamic";

let str = /.*Raj.*/;
console.log(str);
console.log(typeof(str));


let stra = eval(`/.*${filter}+.*/`);
console.log(stra);
console.log(typeof(stra));
```

Comment: We can use eval

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid posting code only answer and provide some explanation for it.