# Moongose MongoDB: LIKE operator in search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After read some solutions to use "LIKE" in Mongoose:

[Mongoose.js: Find user by username LIKE value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824010/mongoose-js-find-user-by-username-like-value)

[How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

[Mongodb dynamic like operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362113/mongodb-dynamic-like-operator)

I'm using this code to simulate "SQL LIKE" in Mongoose:

**Find: *'joseph'*   -->  Result:  *Josephine Doyle***

```
var word = 'joseph';

User
    .find({name: new RegExp(word, 'i')})
    .sort('-created')
    .exec(function(err, users){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(users);
        }
    });
```

The result of this is the user Josephine Doyle, OK.

Now I want to use the same code, but with this word to search:

**Find: *'josephine do'*   -->  Result:  *Josephine Doyle***

```
var word = 'josephine do';
```

OK, works too...

**More examples than works:**

- Find: *'josephine doyle'*   -->  Result:  *Josephine Doyle*
- Find: *'jos doyle'*   -->  Result:  *Josephine Doyle*

**But, I want to solve this case of problems:**

- Find: *'doyle josephine'*   -->  Result:  *{}*
- Find: *'do josephine'*   -->  Result:  *{}*
- Find: *'doyle jo'*   -->  Result:  *{}*

  ***(Different order words doesn't work)***
- Find: 'josephine

  doyle'   -->  Result:  *{}*

  ***(With more than one space between words doesn't work)***

Any suggestions? Maybe another RegEx? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string and searching each word using `$and`.

Something like:

```
var name = 'doyle josephine';

var toSearch = name.split(" ").map(function(n) {
    return {
        name: new RegExp(n.trim(), 'i')
    };
});

User
    .find({ $and: toSearch })
```